# CDRs and antigen-binding sites

Tags: immunology, immune-system, antibody, antigen

Are complementarity determining regions (CDRs) not the same thing as antigen-binding sites?

If not, what is the difference?

An old exam question states:

> "Clarify how CDRs are related to the antigen binding sites"

To answer this I would simply say that CDRs provide a binding surface that is complementary to that of the antigen. Is that what is meant by the question or am I missing something?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each antigen binding site (also known as [paratope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paratope)) is made up of six complementarity-determining regions (CDRs) - three from each of the light and heavy chains.